# VSCode / Docker devcontainer.json Issue

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

Within *VSCode* there is an extention *Remote - Containers* with option to save the installed extensions to a file name `devcontainer.json`. This allows VSCode to install the necessary extensions when you are using a container-based environment.

However, this is not working. When I select the following option, no file is created. Or if I create the file it is not updated.

[image: Add to container.json option]

My VSCode setup is:
* Win10
* VSCode 1.44.2
* This is being performed via the WSL2 remote connection.

Many Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand if this should be a docker or a vscode related question. How are you working with docker and vscode? What is the container about you spun up? Can you post more information like the Dockerfile or the devcontainer.json? Which extension you are talking about? What are you doing in vscode to receive your goal? Best

Comment: Your question needs more details for someone to understand what exactly you want to achieve and what you have done till now

Comment: But the question contains that (?)

Comment: @felix001, your question is not clear, can you provide more details, e.g `Dockerfile` and how is VSCode is related to the container, what this container running?

Comment: @felix001, few things are not clear. What container are you attaching to? Also you said `However, when I select add to devcontainer.json from the extensions panel`, In extension panel I don't see any such option, if you can few screenshots and a bit more details it will help solve the issue

Comment: Will update question etc later . Thanks

Comment: Do you have the `Remote - WSL` extension also installed? I believe that also will be needed

Comment: Yes i have that installed.

Comment: So are you attaching a container inside WSL2? Or just WSL itself. For me the button created files inside WSL but not into container, as it required Docker Desktop before doing anything container related.

Comment: I was in WSL2. But had not connected to a container.

Comment: is this working fine with local docker desktop setup ?

Comment: I have docker desktop. If i use WSL remote connected it doesnt work. Local connection does. Remote Docker connection also doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed *Remote - Containers* fails to put extensions' ids into `devcontainer.json`... unless you create the `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` **AND** unless you put there some content:

```
{
  "extensions": []
}
```

should be enough.
Actually, even

```
{
}
```

is enough.

Comment: seems to work for a standard connection aka it doesnt work when using the WSL remote connection (?)

Comment: Are you trying to modify `devcontainer.json` inside container or even from inside container?

Comment: Nope just when I’m in WSL is the WSL connection

Comment: I don't really understand your setup. Where is your workspace and how it is shared among Windows, WSL and a container? You're obviously using *Remote Containers* AND *Remote WSL* at the same time. Why? I don't have Windows, but I'm under impression that to work with a container you need only *Remote Containers* extension. With both extensions running you have at least 3 places where you need to place `devcontainer.json` with some content in it (or share):

Comment: the local workspace, the WSL filesystem, the container filesystem. Also *Remote Containers* need to be installed at least twice - locally (it will update `devcontainer.json` in a local workspace), in WSL (to update `devcontainer.json` in WSL), and maybe even in a container to (to update `devcontainer.json` in there). That looks really complicated.

Comment: And when I tried to install *Remote Containers* into a container the extension is disabled in there. So most probably it's one of those extensions that can run only locally.

Comment: When you are in WSL is *Remote Containers* listed under *WSL - installed*, or under *Local - installed*? Wherever it is installed and **enabled** it is the only place it can work in. Because otherwise *VSCode* would have no way to decide in what context `"Add to devcontainer.json"` menu option should be executed.

Comment: Remote Containers is installed in local but not in WSL. But there is no option to install this in WSL. Thanks for help so far...